# reading entries from multiple files

Tags: awk

I have few files like `A.txt`, `B.txt` and `C.txt`, each having a only single number in it i.e `A.txt` has `45`, `B.txt` has `35` and `C.txt` has `100`. How could I read these entries from each files and report with its corresponding file name.

output:

```
45 A.txt
35 B.txt
100 C.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '{ print $0 " " FILENAME }' A.txt B.txt C.txt
```

Output:

```
45 A.txt
35 B.txt
100 C.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Another answer, which doesn't involve awk but gives you the output in another format:

```
$ grep "" *.txt
A.txt:45
B.txt:35
C.txt:100
```

Answer (score 4):

With shell only:

```
for f in {A,B,C}.txt; do echo $(<$f) $f; done
```

Output:

```
45 A.txt
35 B.txt
100 C.txt
```

Comment: I think that one's better than mine!